# How to select edge disjoint cycles with maximum combined length?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, cycle

Given a graph I want to select cycles in the graph such that

1. They are edge disjoint, may not be vertex disjoint.
2. Their combined length is as much as possible.

Any tip will help.
Thanks.

Comment: Either you want maximum or minimum, edit your question accordingly

Comment: Maximum, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Given a weighted directed graph, prepare a flow network by setting the capacity of each arc to 1 and the cost of each arc to minus its weight. Compute a min-cost circulation (must be integral; most algorithms will do this for free). Form the subgraph consisting of the arcs with flow 1. This subgraph is Eulerian; by modifying an algorithm to find an Euler tour, we can decompose it into arc-disjoint cycles.